# Change notification when a bounty gets no answer

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications, global-inbox, no-answers

Currently the bounty I set on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221283/the-android-app-does-not-have-obvious-access-to-the-help-center) has expired with no answer.

The message displayed on the bounty is:

> This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from C Rags that ended 1 hour ago. You have 22 hours to award the bounty

However this makes no sense as there is no answer whatsoever to which the bounty can be awarded.

The notification I got in my inbox also was of the same kind:

> Your bounty on question "..." is completed and will be auto awarded in 24 hours

I request that this notification and the message in the question be changed to reflect the "no-answer" status of the question.

Comment: unanswered, so I won't mark as dupe (even though on meta I can): ["You have x hours to award the bounty" when there are no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108370/you-have-x-hours-to-award-the-bounty-when-there-are-no-answers)

Comment: Thanks, but I think this has done its job if more attention is drawn to the original question. I tried searching for a question that addressed this issue before I posted this question but could not find it. Thanks for pointing out @KateGregory