# Bounty expiration notification for question with no answers

Tags: support, bounties

I just got a notification because a bounty I put on a question is expiring. But the question has no answers. Is there any call-to-action the system is trying to give me, other than just letting me know I'm gonna lose the rep?

Comment: No, no call to action, just a technical issue. There is already a feature request asking to change it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248020/change-notification-when-a-bounty-gets-no-answer