# Is there any help section available to understand how to type multi word tags in SE Android App?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, android-app, search

When I tried to type SQL Server tag in Stack Overflow section of Stack Exchange Android App, I didn't find expected result. I mean different versions of SQL Server and the questions tagged with SQL Server alone.

> [image]

Later I found if we search as [Sql-Server] we will get all the versions of SQL Server through which we can search our expected question.

> [image]

But it took some time for me to understand this. My question is, Do we have any document or help section on how to search multi word tags in Android App for new user?

Comment: That's just how tag search is... on the entire network. The app isn't special.

Comment: @Catija yes I understand that it will be common to all apps. But I found it in SO hence pointed that as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a regular user of SE Android app, I have to sadly say: no, there's no help section on *anything*.

The current mobile apps seem targeted for existing power users who have understood how SE sites work already. This is more problematic for [advanced search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), compared to the web version where there's a drop-down "Advanced Search Tips" hint on the sidebar.

There are some feature requests for including help section:

- [There's no help in Help in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217790/theres-no-help-in-help-in-android-app)
- [Android app needs help and new user guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221303/android-app-needs-help-and-new-user-guidance?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [The Android app does not have obvious access to the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221283/the-android-app-does-not-have-obvious-access-to-the-help-center)

However, take note that the development of mobile apps is suspended for now since the developers were pulled into Team DAG (read more on [Are more mobile app review or moderation features coming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389)).